# Place Snackbar at highest z order to avoid from being blocked by AutoCompleteTextView drop down

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-windowmanager, android-snackbar

I have a `Snackbar` which is as follows:

[image]

However, if the drop down of the `AutoCompleteTextView` is too long, the drop down will block the `Snackbar`.

[image]

**As you can see in the above image, the `Snackbar` is actually showing. However, its visibility is blocked by the long drop down. You can see from the above image**

I try to use the following `Snackbar code`. Adding `bringToFront()` doesn't help much.

```
private void showSnackbar(String message) {
    Snackbar snackbar
            = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.getView().bringToFront();
    snackbar.show();
}
```

`R.id.content` is a `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:background="?attr/MyActivityBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="?attr/headerShadow" />
```

Is there any good way, to avoid `Snackbar` from being covered by `AutoCompleteTextView`'s drop down?

Comment: Do you consider having part of the drop down covered by the snack bar to be better?? Or are you willing to limit the height of the drop down?

Comment: We prefer not to limit the height of drop down.

Comment: That would prevent the user from clicking the last item...

Comment: I agree with @dev.bmax. It would be a poor UX to have the last item of the drop down blocked or partially hidden. Making the drop down just a little shorter seems like a much better option.

Comment: And if you prefer not to limit the height of the drop down, what if it has 50 items? Wouldn't a scrollable list be fine?

Comment: It's scrollable by default.

Comment: What kind of content is in your snackbar that you don't want hidden?

Comment: Rather than changing the z index of the snackbar, what about trying to make the scrollable list have a shorter horizontal height. I don't know how to do that off hand but even if it is not possible with the built in functionality, you could make your own custom list.

Comment: In theory `ListPopupWindow` material style has elevation of `16dp`, so if you set `Snackbar` elevation to be bigger by calling `snackbar.getView().setElevation([float])`, that might work. But will work only for Lollipop+.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng, see you, my post. please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might have a solution for that case. Of course, there are some assumptions but maybe the solution would suit you.

The key here is putting `AutoCompleteTextView` inside `CoordinatorLayout` and add custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` to it.

1. Create appropriate `Behavior` for your class:

   ```
   public class AutoCompleteTextViewBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<AutoCompleteTextView> {

       public AutoCompleteTextViewBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, AutoCompleteTextView child, View dependency) {
           return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Override a method `layoutDependsOn`:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, AutoCompleteTextView child, View dependency) {
       return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
   }
   ```
3. Get reference to `AutoCompleteTextView` popup view:

   Unfortunately I haven't found a simple solution for that. However can be done via reflection.

   ```
   @Nullable
   private View getPopupList(AutoCompleteTextView child) {
       try {
           Field popupField;
           Class clazz;
           if (child instanceof AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView) {
               clazz = child.getClass().getSuperclass();
           } else {
               clazz = child.getClass();
           }
           popupField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
           popupField.setAccessible(true);
           ListPopupWindow popup = (ListPopupWindow) popupField.get(child);
           Field popupListViewField = popup.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDropDownList");
           popupListViewField.setAccessible(true);
           return (View) popupListViewField.get(popup);
       } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
4. Override `onDependentViewChanged` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, final AutoCompleteTextView child, View dependency) {
       if (popupList == null) {
           popupList = getPopupList(child);
           if (popupList == null) {
               return super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
           }
       }
       int dropdownBottom = child.getBottom() + child.getDropDownVerticalOffset() + popupList.getHeight();
       int snackBarTop = dependency.getTop();
       int difference = dropdownBottom - snackBarTop;
       if (difference > 0) {
           child.setDropDownHeight(popupList.getHeight() - difference);
           return true;
       } else {
           child.setDropDownHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       }
       return super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
   }
   ```
5. Apply the behavior to `AutocompleteTextView` in `.xml`:

   ```
   app:layout_behavior="com.example.package.AutoCompleteTextViewBehaviour"/>
   ```

Of course this is a very basic solution, that for example does not animate list height, but I think this is a good start. Here is the full [gist](https://gist.github.com/RobertZagorski/1cc49332f743db74b8b75d878bf798ba).

Comment: Can you clarify just, why do you need the reference to mDropDownList?  Isn't child.getDropDownHeight() appropriate?

Comment: By default calling the function `child.getDropDownHeight() ` returns `-2`, which is the equivalent of value `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams#WRAP_CONTENT`. An exact height is needed.

Comment: we set the height of the popup only when the SnackbarLayout changes, right ?

Comment: Exactly. And only when popup intersects `Snackbar`

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate and adjust the height of the popup as an alternative.
In the following picture, I am setting the dropdown height as bellow:

```
textView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
  textView.dropDownHeight = snackbarView.top - textView.bottom
}
```

[image]

This calculation is for the case where the suggestion list's height is long enough. You might want to set that property to `WRAP_CONTENT` instead.

As far as I know, it is not possible to change the "z-order" unless you add the SnackBar directly to the `WindowManager`. `AutoCompleteTextView` internally is using `ListPopupWindow` to show the suggestions popup and `ListPopupWindow` has the window type of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL` = 1000 which is higher than the Activity's Window type which is of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION` = 2.

Comment: This solution is much concise.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I could get it to work with `setZ`:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(container, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.getView().setZ(200);
snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set `android:dropDownHeight` to a fixed `dp` value? You can even define it to be dynamically based on screen size by reference a `dimension` resource. It is one line of code, it solves your problem, easy to maintain and to understand (in six month you will ask yourself, what the whole `Behavior` stuff is used for).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to take many thinks in consideration:

- there must be space for all. keyboard, snackbar and autocomplete Textview
- you cannot change the keyboard height (by your app), so you have to change the height of the autocomplete TextView to be above the snackbar (which is above the keyboard)